# TinyMCE UTF-8 saving to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, tinymce

I send TinyMCE input to POST (a php file), then save it in MySQL Database.

The input has UTF-8 (Turkish characters). So when I type `Türkçe` inside the TinyMCE input and send it to post, PHP backend receives this string :

```
<p>T&uuml;rk&ccedil;e</p>
```

How can I convert it back to `Türkçe` so I can save it correctly in MySQL ?

### P.S.:

MySQL is set to `utf8_unicode_ci` collation, so it can save UTF-8 characters correctly.

I need to convert them in PHP, I guess.

Or a way for TinyMCE to send them correctly?

Thanks for any help !

### P.S. 2:

I think that this issue is about TinyMCE itself, so I guess the solution will be converting the TinyMCE output (either in TinyMCE javascript, or the receiving PHP script).

i.e. :  I don't think changing my PHP configuration is the solution.

### P.S. 3

I guess these characters like `&uuml;` are the HTML equivalents of Turkish characters, so `htmlspecialchars_decode()` should work, but it does not accept Turkish characters. Maybe a way for `htmlspecialchars_decode` to decode UTF-8 Characters ?

Comment: Is UTF-8 set as default charset in your php.ini ?

Comment: @Kei Maybe I can set it in my local WampServer, but I cannot modify the php.ini in my web host, so I don't know :) But other (standard) inputs can receive utf-8 text and save in the database correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Well, since I can't help you much more if you don't give me more details, could you run http://www.php.net/mb_detect_encoding on your $_POST['variable'] ? By this output we can understand many things

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       tinymce.init({
           entity_encoding : "raw"
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tinyMCE.init
({  entities : "Ü = Ü ü = ü Ç = Ç Ç = ç Ö = Ö ö = ö",
    theme : "advanced",
    mode : "textareas",
```

Comment: Code only answer are discouraged. Please consider explaining what you code is doing and how it answers the question.